# react-native android app crashes on launch using branch.io react-native-branch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm finding difficulties while using the branch.io(react-native-branch) integration for android for deep-linking app is getting stop  after applying changes in mainactivity.java.

react:v17.0.2
react-native:v0.66.4
react-native-branch:v^5.4.0

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eneff.branchandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.eneff.branchandroid.CustomApplicationClass"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="branchandroid" android:host="open" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Branch App Links -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="uobg.app.link" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      
        <!-- Branch keys -->
        <!-- (Omit if setting keys in branch.json) -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_gdzsepIaUf7wG3dEWb3aBkmcutm0PwJa"/>
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test_edwDakKcMeWzJ3hC3aZs9kniyuaWGCTa"/>
      
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
import io.branch.rnbranch.*;
import android.content.Intent;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "G4Plus";
  }
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    RNBranchModule.initSession(getIntent().getData(), this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   super.onNewIntent(intent);
   if (intent != null &&
      intent.hasExtra("branch_force_new_session") && 
      intent.getBooleanExtra("branch_force_new_session",false)) {
      RNBranchModule.onNewIntent(intent);}
   }
  
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.g4plus;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;
import io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchModule;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
          return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); // <- add
        }

        // overide for branch
        

      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    RNBranchModule.getAutoInstance(this);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.g4plus.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have taken references from the branch.io(react-native-branch) developer guide
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native

Answer (score 0):

try to downgrade this to version 5.0.0 I was having the same issue on my setup